# Why is the first tab (\t) not in line with the others?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tabs

I made a frequency analysis program. It returns this sorted tuple for a certain string:

```
frequency = [('Z', 110), ('D', 81), ('O', 78), ('V', 69), ('I', 69), ('J', 64), ('C', 58), ('N', 56), ('M', 54), ('Y', 35), ('G', 30), ('P', 27), ('B', 24), ('H', 23), ('X', 23), ('R', 19), ('T', 16), ('W', 15), ('A', 12), ('K', 12), ('F', 8), ('Q', 8), ('E', 2), ('S', 1)]
```

So I want to print the cipher letter and its frequency. In addition, I have an alphabet ordered by letter frequency in English(`ordered_alphabet = "ETAOINSRHLDCUMFPGWYBVKXJQZ"`) I want to put each of these letters next to my cipher letter and frequency to help me figure out what the cipher letter could be.

So I do:

```
for item in frequency:
    print("%s : %s \t \t %s" % (item[0], item[1], ordered_alphabet[frequency.index(item)]))
```

This returns:

```
Z : 110          E
D : 81       T
O : 78       A
V : 69       O
I : 69       I
J : 64       N
C : 58       S
N : 56       R
M : 54       H
Y : 35       L
G : 30       D
P : 27       C
B : 24       U
H : 23       M
X : 23       F
R : 19       P
T : 16       G
W : 15       W
A : 12       Y
K : 12       B
F : 8        V
Q : 8        K
E : 2        X
S : 1        J
```

**Why is the first ordered_letter(`E`) not in line with the other ordered letters?** I used `\t` for all of them.

Comment: Because 110 is longer than 81?

Comment: Then why is `V` still in line even though 12 is longer than 8? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Because that doesn’t push you over a tab stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tabulations don't guarantee alignment, and tab width depend on editor/terminal settings. You could try `str.format` instead to fix the max field sizes and drop using tabulations. Use only spaces for deterministic formatting.

for instance (I hardcoded 3 as the size, but you may want to precompute max size):

```
print("{} : {:3}   {}" .format (item[0], item[1], ordered_alphabet[frequency.index(item)]))
```

without harcoding, & max size computation:

```
maxdigit = len(str(max(x[1] for x in frequency)))
for item in frequency:
    print("{} : {:{}}   {}" .format (item[0], item[1], maxdigit, ordered_alphabet[frequency.index(item)]))
```

gets me

```
Z : 110   E
D :  81   T
O :  78   A
V :  69   O
I :  69   I
J :  64   N
C :  58   S
N :  56   R
M :  54   H
Y :  35   L
G :  30   D
P :  27   C
B :  24   U
H :  23   M
X :  23   F
R :  19   P
T :  16   G
W :  15   W
A :  12   Y
K :  12   B
F :   8   V
Q :   8   K
E :   2   X
S :   1   J
```

Comment: What do the braces replace? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: instead of hard coding 3 might wanna suggest OP to find the largest number :D other wise like always good answer

Comment: @MooingRawr that's true!

Comment: @MilanTom the brackets are there for place holders read up on str.format, it's a useful function.

Answer (score 3):

Add some spacing to your 2nd string formatting (`%s`) and it should align everything else after it

```
frequency = [('Z', 110), ('D', 81), ('O', 78), ('V', 69), ('I', 69), ('J', 64), ('C', 58), ('N', 56), ('M', 54), ('Y', 35), ('G', 30), ('P', 27), ('B', 24), ('H', 23), ('X', 23), ('R', 19), ('T', 16), ('W', 15), ('A', 12), ('K', 12), ('F', 8), ('Q', 8), ('E', 2), ('S', 1)]
for item in frequency:
    print("%s : %-5s \t %s" % (item[0], item[1], ordered_alphabet[frequency.index(item)]))

Z : 110    E
D : 81     T
O : 78     A
V : 69     O
I : 69     I
J : 64     N
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically need some padding for 2nd field.

Change `print("%s : %s` to `print("%s : %3s` : `3` here says : Pad the field with spaces upto 3 characters

Link : https://repl.it/N2tX

Output:

```
Z : 110          E
D :  81          T
O :  78          A
V :  69          O
I :  69          I
J :  64          N
C :  58          S
N :  56          R
M :  54          H
Y :  35          L
G :  30          D
P :  27          C
B :  24          U
H :  23          M
X :  23          F
R :  19          P
T :  16          G
W :  15          W
A :  12          Y
K :  12          B
F :   8          V
Q :   8          K
E :   2          X
S :   1          J
```